# Can't login with spring security

Tags: spring-security

I created a simple project to login using spring security.
The composition of my project is presented by screenshot:

[image: this screenshot].

bellow are the required files:

**spring-security.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

 <http auto-config="true">
  <intercept-url pattern="/welcome.jsf" access="ROLE_USER" />
  <form-login login-page="/login.jsf" default-target-url="/welcome.jsf"
   authentication-failure-url="/login.jsf?status=error" />
  <logout logout-success-url="/login.jsf?status=logout" />
 </http>

 <authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider>
   <user-service>
    <user name="walid" password="111" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
   </user-service>
  </authentication-provider>
 </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

**web.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web_1:web-app  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:javaee="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd 
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    id="Spring-Security-Custom-Login-Form_ID" 
    version="2.4">
  <javaee:display-name>HelloWorld</javaee:display-name>
  <javaee:listener>
    <javaee:listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</javaee:listener-class>
  </javaee:listener>
  <javaee:filter>
    <javaee:filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</javaee:filter-name>
    <javaee:filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</javaee:filter-class>
  </javaee:filter>
  <javaee:filter-mapping>
    <javaee:filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</javaee:filter-name>
    <javaee:url-pattern>/*</javaee:url-pattern>
  </javaee:filter-mapping>
  <javaee:context-param>
    <javaee:param-name>contextConfigLocation</javaee:param-name>
    <javaee:param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</javaee:param-value>
  </javaee:context-param>
  <javaee:context-param>
    <javaee:description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</javaee:description>
    <javaee:param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</javaee:param-name>
    <javaee:param-value>client</javaee:param-value>
  </javaee:context-param>
  <javaee:context-param>
    <javaee:param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</javaee:param-name>
    <javaee:param-value>resources.application</javaee:param-value>
  </javaee:context-param>
  <javaee:listener>
    <javaee:listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</javaee:listener-class>
  </javaee:listener>
  <javaee:servlet>
    <javaee:servlet-name>Faces Servlet</javaee:servlet-name>
    <javaee:servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</javaee:servlet-class>
    <javaee:load-on-startup>1</javaee:load-on-startup>
  </javaee:servlet>
  <javaee:servlet-mapping>
    <javaee:servlet-name>Faces Servlet</javaee:servlet-name>
    <javaee:url-pattern>/faces/*</javaee:url-pattern>
  </javaee:servlet-mapping>
</web_1:web-app>
```

**login.xhtml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core">
<body>
 <h3>Enter your username and password</h3>
 <form method="post" action="j_spring_security_check">
  UserName :<input name="j_username" type="text" /> <br />
  Password :<input name="j_password" type="password" /> <br />
  <input value="Login" type="submit" />
 </form>
 
 <br />
 <c:if test="${param.status=='error'}">
  <label style="color:red">Invalid username or password!!</label>
 </c:if>
 <c:if test="${param.status=='logout'}">
  <label style="color:red">Logged out successfully!</label>
 </c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

**welcome.xhtml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
 <h2>Welcome Page</h2>
 <br />
 <a href="j_spring_security_logout"> Logout </a>
</body>
</html>
```

After login with (walid,111), I got [this exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNfKG.png)
Could you please help me solving this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your **web.xml** seems wrong, you can try this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:javaee="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 id="Spring-Security-Database-Authentication_ID" version="2.4">
 <display-name>Spring-Security-Database-Authentication</display-name>
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>JSF Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>JSF Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>JSF Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 <filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
</web-app>
```

HTH